# Сравнение нескольких массивов

Tags: php

Допустим есть 5 массивов (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5), в массивах содержатся id. Необходимо сравнить между собой массивы и записать в новый массив все id встречающиеся во всех массивах. В случае если массив пустой к примеру а2, не сравнивать соответственно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$a1 = array(1,2,3);
$a2 = array(2,3);
$a3 = array(1,3);
$a4 = array(1,2,4);
$a5 = array(4);

$result = array_values(array_unique(array_merge($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5)));
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: array_unique — убирает повторяющиеся значения из массива, а необходимо оставить только те элементы которые встречаются во всех!

Comment: сорри
тогда
$result_array = array_intersect($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5);

Comment: задачу я решил, вышеуказанный метод также не сработает, в условии было указано, что должен встречаться в каждом из массивов, а если один из них пуст то не учитывать его

Answer (score 0):

```
$result_array = array();
$result_array = array_unique($a1 + $a2 + $a3 + $a4 + $a5);
```

Comment: Первая инициализация абсолютно излишня.

Comment: @vp_arth это не инициализация, это обнуление :]

Comment: @Manitikyl, как же Вы в своём ответе обнуление-то и упустили? =) Мне кажется, обнуление — это когда `$a = null; unset($a); $a = [];`

Comment: array_unique — убирает повторяющиеся значения из массива, а необходимо оставить только те элементы которые встречаются во всех!